# make an entry in form where after submission suscess 3 entries out of it will be as it is and rest 3 will become null

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to make a page which is used to enter the bill details, so I created the form in **staffcontentCID.php** which contains my form. 
The form has 6 entries: `userid`, `customerid`, `transactionid`, `itemcode`, `itemquantity`, `itemprice` and the value is being stored in the database using **bill.php**. 
It is successful but need something more in it whenever I submit the form all values are set to null again, so I was thinking of some process where when on submit the form, the form entries (`userid`, `customerid`, `transactionid`) will have the last value entered in them, so that I don't have to re-enter all these again and again and rest entries (`itemcode`, `itemquantity`, `itemprice`) will become null so as I could enter next product with the same ids entered previously. It will continue till last and when I press print button for the bill printing (which I will add in my code) all values will again goes to null.

The code of form is:

```
<div class="w3-half" style="display:inline;height:400px;">
<div class="w3-container">

<form action="./database/bill.php" method="post" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:150px;">
<table cellspacing=20px>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>User ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="uid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Customer ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="cid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Transaction ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="tid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Code :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="ic" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Quantity :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="iq" type="number">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Price :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="ip" type="number">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-half" style="display:inline;height:400px;">
<div class="w3-container">

transaction id :
</div>

</div>
```

and code for bill.php is

```
<?php
//store.php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','master');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//go query

$r = $_POST['cid'];
$e = $_POST['uid'];
$q = $_POST['ic'];
$j = $_POST['tid'];
$h = $_POST['ip'];
$i = $_POST['iq'];
$x = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into transactionb values('".$j."','".$r."','".$e."','".$q."','".$i."','".$h."')");
echo mysqli_error($conn);
if($x){echo 'success';
echo '<script>window.location = "../staffentryCID.php"</script>';}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `ajax` and `jQuery`.

**Note:** If you use this then your form submission will act differently in the sense that the page doesn't have to load and take you to `bill.php` instead it sends the form to bill.php and the form will be inserted into your database without leaving the current page. And secondly using this you must include the `jQuery` library to your script. You can just replace your code with these below code.

```
<div class="w3-half" style="display:inline;height:400px;">
<div class="w3-container">

<form id="myForm" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:150px;">
<table cellspacing=20px>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>User ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="uid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Customer ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="cid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Transaction ID :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="tid" type="varchar">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Code :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="ic" type="varchar" id="ic">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Quantity :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="iq" type="number" id="iq">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
<b>Item Price :</b>
</center>
</td>
<td>
<input name="ip" type="number" id="ip">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-half" style="display:inline;height:400px;">
<div class="w3-container">

transaction id :
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form#myForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the page from going to bill.php
        $.ajax({
            url: "./database/bill.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(){
                // This code below will reset the values of the input field you want it be empty after form submission
                $('input#ic').val('');
                $('input#iq').val('');
                $('input#ip').val('');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Now you noticed that I gave the `form` an id  and also the `input` fields you want it to be empty after the form submission. Then I reset their value to nothing after the form submission success

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i tried this code but there is a problem i am facing after implementing this code. The values so entered in the form is not going to database table, whenever i click submit all the fields refresh instead of the last three and nor does it insert values in the table. And  one more problem arose when i deep rechecked it again, its written in ajax method "method:post" but still its not using the post method for sending the entries instead its using get method because whenever i send the values the values are displayed in the address bar 
may be there is something missing  ?

Comment: @Ardern If you are having issues with the code then I am sure its your fault. Using `method: "POST" ` or `type: "POST"` is the same. Now this is how you fix the error. If your page reloads when you submit the form then you have generated an error some where. So you check your console.log.   For better result just take away your code and replace it with mine. And take note. If you are offline then the code won't work because the `jQuery` library link requires network. But if you insist on using it offline then download the `jQuery` library and replace the script src with the path of

Comment: Your downloaded file, for example `<script src="path/to/file/jquery.js">`. You can download the `jQuery` library from here (https://jquery.com/download/). Here is a working [link](http://stephensangkn.org/asked/) with the above code. Try it and you will see its working. As for the insertion to your database I strongly believe that if you get your jQuery ajax code right then the form must be inserted into your database

Comment: thanks for solution , i got the problem i was working offline all the time , downloaded the library itself now .

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark your question as answered. And also up vote